# How to get X-Zumo-auth token in Azure Mobile service

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I am planning to automate some scenarios in my app. basically 5 different users calls some apis on using Mobile client app. Now in order to simulate that,I need to call my server apis with X-ZUMO-Auth, just wandering how can I gt the X-Zumo-auth for 5 different test users. I tried calling https:///.auth/login/facebook/  and then https:///.auth/me which gives me oath token for Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following function to create a token valid for 24h.

You need to have your SigningKey (if it's the newer AppServices mobile you can just use Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY") instead.

```
    public static string CreateToken(string userid)
    {
        JwtSecurityToken token = AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken(new Claim[] { new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userid) },
             ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningKey"],
             ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"],
             ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"],
             TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
        return token.RawData;
    }
```